# Atualizar uma variável de seção asp sem atualizar a página

Tags: javascript, ajax, session, asp

Estou quebrando a cabeça pra tentar resolver esse problema, mas sem sucesso...

Estou com uma loja virtual criada pro outro programador que desapareceu. Pra variar  código está sem documentação.

Para calcular o frete no carrinho de compras ele chama um outro arquivo asp que por sua vez chama o webservice dos correios e retorna o valor em post para o carrinho de compras. Este valor então é carregado em uma variável de sessão.

Formulário de cálculo de frete dentro do carrinho de compras:

```
<form method=post action=calcula_cep.asp>
<input name="met" id="met1" type="radio" value="PAC" />PAC (até 10 dias úteis)     
<input name="met" id="met2" type="radio" value="SEDEX" />SEDEX (até 4 dias úteis)
<input type=hidden name=peso value="<%=session("total_peso")%>">
<input type=text name="cep_1" id="cep_1" size=5 onkeyup="pulaCampo();" maxlength="5" class=campo value="<%=cepp1%>" readonly="readonly">-<input type=text name="cep_2" id="cep_2" size=3 maxlength="3" class=campo value="<%=cepp2%>" readonly="readonly">
<input type=submit name=submit value="Calcular" class="botao">
</form>
```

O Arquivo calcula_cep.asp faz o chamado do webservice dos correios e retorna a variável Valor_1 por post para o carrinho de compras:

```
if len(request("Valor_1")) > 0 then

   if len(session("log_cli"))>0 then
            Session("vTarifa") = Replace(request("Valor_1"),".",",")
     else
            Session("sTarifa") = replace(request("Valor_1"),".",",")
     end if

end if
```

O que estou tentando fazer é uma requisição ajax para o calcula_cep.asp atualizar o valor de Session("vTarifa") e Session("sTarifa"). Minha dúvida é como atualizar a sessão e como imprimir este valor atualizado no carrinho, sem atualizar a página (por javascript?).

Comment: Tem certeza que o que você quer é atualizar uma variável de sessão? Não seria um campo de form, ou alguma coisa na página, para usar quando enviado? Variável de sessão só faz sentido pra manter o estado da aplicação para aquele visitante, e quando o cliente está vendo a página, o asp nao está mais sendo executado. Detalhe: com variável de sessão, se o cara abrir 2 abas de compra e fizer operação em uma delas, a outra pode ficar completamente fora de sincronismo. Dá pra usar, mas compensa visualizar bem o que vai acontecer do lado do servidor e o que vai do lado do cliente.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se essa é a melhor forma de fazer. Estou tentando adaptar o código do carrinho justamente porque o cliente perde a sessão e é deslogado quando faz o cálculo do frete que recarrega a página. Como o código está muito mal documentado, quero alterar o mínimo possível pra não dar erro em outras partes do site. Os dados do carrinho estão sendo gravados uma variável session() que é lida pelo arquivo de checkout. Estava pensando em alterá-la por AJAX para quando o cliente clicasse no link do checkout ele irá buscar isso no servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de utilizar um botão submit, crie um botão comum e chame uma função contendo ajax para chamar esta página, um botão submit sempre a recarregará

```
<input type="button" onclick="calcula_cep()" value="calcular" class="botao">
```

Javascript

```
function calcula_cep() {
$.post("calcula_cep.asp",null,
     function(resposta){
       if (resposta){
          $("#controle_carrinho").html(resposta);
       }
  }
}
```

Vbscript

```
if len(request("Valor_1")) > 0 then

   if len(session("log_cli"))>0 then
        Session("vTarifa") = Replace(request("Valor_1"),".",",")
        response.write Session("vTarifa")
     else
        Session("sTarifa") = replace(request("Valor_1"),".",",")
        response.write Session("sTarifa")
     end if

end if
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Tinha me esquecido dessa pergunta... eu terminei fazendo parecido com a sua solução, criando dois novos campos hidden para o frete que são carregados pelo ajax e na página do checkout eu carrego esses campos na sessão antes de carregar a página...